# Java: In Parsing a String , Ignore what is in parenthesis

Tags: java

I have a method which is in a condition string and if there is no spaces after and before a logical operator, it throws error. I have an issue if for example it finds a word like "more" or it finds "or" it gives error. This is an example and below that is my code.

condition: (`da_cargue_hechos_mora_abonados) and s(da_cliente_diario_scl) and s(da_e_abonado_diario_pos) and s(da_e_abonado_diario_pre) and s(da_dim_situacion_scl) and s(da_dim_oficina_scl)`

```
Code:

 private static Job checkSpacesInCondition(Job job) {
String condition = null;
condition = job.getCondition();

// If null, no check needed
if (condition != null) {
    condition = condition.toLowerCase();
    condition = condition.replaceAll("&&", "and");
    condition = condition.replaceAll("&", "and");

    for (String word : CONDITION_OPERATORS) {
    Pattern logicalPattern = Pattern.compile("\\S" + word + "|"
        + word + "\\S");
    Matcher logicalMatcher = logicalPattern.matcher(condition);
    boolean foundNoSpace = logicalMatcher.find();
    if (foundNoSpace) {
        job.addWarning(JobWarning.SPACES_AFTER_LOGICAL_OPERATOR);
    }
    }
}

return job;
}
```

Comment: can you clarify your question a bit?

Comment: You can use \\(*\\) to find any character or string which has parenthesis around it.

Comment: Tell us what error it throws (along with a stack trace) and give us some examples of where it throws this error and also where it gives the incorrect output, along with what you want the output to be (and put it separately rather than as part of sentences).

Comment: Yes, I am only looking for logical operands (and, or, &&, &, etc) in a condition phrase. but the program can not tell if for instance 'or' is the operand or part of the word like 'mora'. I am thinking just to ignor the check for whatever is in the prantesis. is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions for parsing "condition expressions", especially if you allow nesting with paranthesis. Regular expressions don't work with this. Use regular expressions for parsing regular languages. For non-regular languages use a real parser-generators, e.g. ANTLR.

Comment: It does not look like the OP is trying to parse the condition. All he wants is some crude pre-validation that checks for simple common mistakes.